# ActiveRecord appears to leak memory when connecting to multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Rails app that downloads a SQLite database on request, saves it a a `TempFile` and connects to it using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`. All the app does is return the entire database as JSON (database is about 10 MB in size). After each request, I explicitly call `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!`. After each request to my app (on my dev box) I noticed that the amount of memory used by the app appears to be ever increasing. How can I stop this from happining?

Just for some numbers:

When I started my app, each worker was using about 100-200m of memory. After less than 100 requests (each request pulls the same DB), each worker is using 500m. I've seen this grow to about 700m each, at which point I have to kill the server because my desktop lags too much.

Comment: After doing some research, I stumbled upon some relevant information. ActiveRecord caches the results from queries, so it is likely that ActiveRecord is not leaking information, but is instead caching the databases unnecessarily. Unfortunately, I don't have the expertise to fixed this problem myself. How can I get active record to perform queries without caching?

Comment: Just did some testing and I don't believe that the SQLite3 adapter uses the query cache so I'm somewhat at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really ActiveRecord cache problem ,try to remove it (it is middleware)

In application.rb:

```
config.middleware.delete "ActiveRecord::QueryCache"
```